# jQuery Alignment - Relative to Browser Window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, css-position

With help from various websites, I've created a very simple pop-up box using javascript that contains my contact information. I'm happy with how it works, except that the popup window that appears is positioned absolutely, and I want to have it appear relative to the browser window (ie I want the pop up to appear in the centre of the browser window, regardless of where you are on the page when you click the info icon).

I'm comfortable with HTML, but not with javascript. I know that relative positioning works very differently in javascript, but I cannot get my head around how to fix this. Any advice would be appreciated.

The webpage is here: http://www.thirstlabmedia.com/

The script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle( div_id ) {
    var el = document.getElementById( div_id );
    if( el.style.display == 'none' ) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function blanket_size( popUpDivVar ) {
    if( typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined' ) {
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    }
    else {
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if( ( viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight ) && ( viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight ) ) {
        blanket_height = viewportheight;
    }
    else {
        if( document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight ) {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
        }
        else {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    var blanket = document.getElementById( 'blanket' );
    blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById( popUpDivVar );
    popUpDiv_height = window.innerHeight / 2 - 200;
    popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos( popUpDivVar ) {
    if( typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined' ) {
        viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
    }
    else {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if( ( viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth ) && ( viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth ) ) {
        window_width = viewportwidth;
    }
    else {
        if( document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth ) {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
        }
        else {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById( popUpDivVar );
    window_width = window_width / 2 - 200;
    popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup( windowname ) {
    blanket_size( windowname );
    window_pos( windowname );
    toggle( 'blanket' );
    toggle( windowname );
}
</script>
```

(My apologies for placing it all on one line; the website is created through Cargo Collective, and it doesn't accept script unless it's all placed on one line).

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `position : fixed`:

```
#my-element {
    position : fixed;
    top      : 50%;
    left     : 50%;
    margin   : -100px 0 0 -250px;
    width    : 500px;
    height   : 200px;
    z-index  : 1000;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/huRcV/1/

This centers a 500x200px element in the `viewport`. The negative margins are used to center the element with respect to its dimensions. If the user scrolls the page, the element will stay centered in the `viewport`.

Docs for `position`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position

> ### fixed
>
> Do not leave space for the element.  Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page.

You *can* do this with JavaScript but it's probably better to use the CSS version. If you do want to use jQuery here is a quick example:

```
var $myElement = $('#my-element');
$(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
    $myElement.css({
        top : ($(this).scrollTop() + ($(this).height() / 2)),
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/huRcV/ (notice that `position : fixed` is changed to `position : absolute` for this demo)

Comment: `fixed` isn't supported < `IE8`. just saying

Comment: IE7 supports `position : fixed`, I tested it on a project just last week. http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed

Comment: strange, it did nothing for me when I ran the test through IE7. in IE8 the element becomes position `fixed` but not in IE7.

Comment: Seems like a `doctype` issue or something. What `doctype` is being used? In standards it should work fine.

Comment: I had IE7 standards (page default), though in the jsfiddle it appears to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/huRcV/3/. Shrug

Comment: Of course! I'd spent the last while playing around with positioning in the javascript, and forgot entirely that I could also use the CSS. Greatly appreciated!